# Oracle ORA-01086: savepoint never established

Tags: oracle

I am trying to set a savepoint and the rollback to that point when I have a problem. But I get the following message:

> SQL execution error, ORA-01086: savepoint 'LASTSAVE' never established ORA-06212: at line 1".

I have made sure there are no commits until then end but still get the error. I have also wrapped it up in a transaction.

Sites like [Oradoctor](http://oradoctor.com/) do not give any help (action) for this.

Comment: Need to see your code, but in the mean time - see this asktom: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:18202801725435

Answer (score 6):

Could it be because you have committed - perhaps by calling some ddl?